# Find, rename and copy files to a new directory

Tags: filemanager, cp

I have 3 files under a directory that represents the `time` which is under a directory that represents a `date`. Each `time` directory has similar files. I'm basically saving earth's magnetosphere measurements.

[image]

Now what I'm trying to do is grab all `ycut2.gif` files, rename them sequentially with respect to the time and copy it to a directory `ycut2` which will be located under the `date` directory, so I can combine them to create a gif for each day.

For instance,

```
14:58:31 > ycut2.gif -----(rename)--> 00.gif
15:21:39 > ycut2.gif -----(rename)--> 01.gif
15:52:30 > ycut2.gif -----(rename)--> 02.gif and so on...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy! You can count in `bash` and produce/read a list of filenames:

```
declare -i num=0
destination="$PWD" # set to destination of files
find . -type f -name 'ycut2.gif` -print | sort | while read fn ; do
    num=$(($num + 1 ))
# following line assumes no more than 99 files
    j=printf "%02d" $num
    cp "$fn" "$destination/$j.gif"
done
```